# Different values and number formatting with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" name="number" />
```

I want show the value for example "79798779" as "797.987,79" but post the value as "797987.79". I am using [this plugin](http://www.jquerypriceformat.com/) for formatting value. How can I change the value in post?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to do this manualy (I think).
HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit()" ... > ... </form>
```

JS:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (from, to) {
    return this.split(from).join(to); // string replace-all-trick
};

function onFormSubmit() {
    var value = $('#yourInput').val();
    var changedValue = value.replaceAll('.', '').replace(',', '.');
    $('#yourInput').val(changedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the value in your submit handler:

```
$('form').submit()
{
    var $field = $(this).find('[name=number]');

    $field.val(
        $field.val().replace(/\./, '').replace(',', '.');
    );
});
```